# Query on three tables returning duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm querying 3 tables Cars, Expenses and Incomes:

```
SELECT c.CarMake, c.CarType, 
(SUM(i.IncomeKMEnd -i.IncomeKMStart)) AS TotalKms,
MAX(i.IncomeKMEnd) as EndingKMs,
CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(int,100.0*(SUM(i.IncomePrice) - SUM(e.ExpenseAmount))/c.CarBuyPrice)) +'%' as IncomePercentage, 
SUM(CASE WHEN e.PaymentType LIKE '%extra%' THEN e.ExpenseAmount ELSE 0 END) AS     ExpenseSum

FROM (Cars AS c  
INNER JOIN Incomes as i ON c.CarID = i.CarID AND (i.IncomeDateFrom BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20140101')) 
INNER JOIN Expenses as e ON i.CarID = e.CarID AND (e.ExpenseDateFrom BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20140101') 

GROUP BY c.CarType, c.CarMake, c.CarBuyPrice
```

There's one car in the Cars table and it is refrenced in the Incomes table 3 times and in the Expenses table 2 times. This query when not grouped returns 6 rows and sums the expenses and incomes 6 times. Is there any way to get it to sum the incomes and expenses correctly?

Comment: Use SELECT DISTINCT ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or newer version then better to use APPLY clause. Also I think you should take into account that Incomes and Expenses can be empty for specific CarId.

```
SELECT  c.CarMake, 
    c.CarType, 
    i.TotalKms,
    i.EndingKMs,
    CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(int,100.0*( isnull( i.IncomePriceTotal, 0) - isnull( e.ExpenseAmountTotal, )) / c.CarBuyPrice)) +'%' as IncomePercentage, 
    e.ExpenseSum
FROM Cars c
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  SUM(i.IncomeKMEnd -i.IncomeKMStart) AS TotalKms,
            MAX(i.IncomeKMEnd) as EndingKMs,
            SUM(i.IncomePrice) as IncomePriceTotal
FROM Incomes i 
WHERE i.CarID = c.CarID 
AND i.IncomeDateFrom BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20140101'
) i
OUTER APPLY
(
SELECT  SUM(e.ExpenseAmount) as ExpenseAmountTotal, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN e.PaymentType LIKE '%extra%' THEN e.ExpenseAmount ELSE 0 END) AS ExpenseSum
FROM Expenses e 
WHERE e.CarID = c.CarID 
AND e.ExpenseDateFrom BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20140101'
) e
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to not join the other table but pull the information out in subqueries.  For example:

```
SELECT c.CarMake, c.CarType,
 (SELECT SUM(IncomePrice) FROM Incomes WHERE CarID = c.CarID and (IncomeDateFrom BETWEEN '20130101' AND '20140101')) SumPrice
FROM Cars AS c
```